# How to handle code of response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to send differend jsons which depend on the response code.

```
 @ApiOperation(value = "saveObject", nickname = "saveObject", httpMethod = "POST")
        @ApiResponses(value = {
                @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
        @PostMapping(value = "/save")
        public void saveUser(@RequestBody ObjectView object) {
            objectService.saveObject(object);
        }
```

Example: if code is 200 this should send

```
data: {
        “result”:”success”
    }
```

if 500

```
 data: {
        “error”:”500”
    }
```

How can I do it with `ResponseBodyAdvice`?

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ResponseView implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object o, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass, ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest,
                                  ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
        return new WrapperObj<Object>(o);
    }

    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    @JsonSerialize
    private class WrapperObj<T> {
        private final Object data;

        public WrapperObj(Object data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RestControllerAdvice is it valid annotation ?

Comment: @SumeshTG: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html

Comment: Oh i see `@ExceptionHandler(CustomNotFoundException.class)
 public ResponseMsg handleNotFoundException(CustomNotFoundException ex) {
  ResponseMsg responseMsg = new ResponseMsg(ex.getMessage());
  return responseMsg;
 }` add handler methods like this into that controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object o, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass, ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {

HttpServletResponse servletResponse = ((ServletServerHttpResponse) serverHttpResponse).getServletResponse();

if(servletResponse.getStatus() == 200) {
        return createYourResponseBodyE_G_200().getBody();

 } else if(servletResponse.getStatus() == 500) {
        return createYourResponseBodyE_G_500().getBody();
 }


public ResponseEntity<Object> createYourResponseBodyE_G_200() {

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(  "data: { \"result\":\"success\" }", HttpStatus.OK);

}

public ResponseEntity<Object> createYourResponseBodyE_G_500() {

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(  "data: { \"error\":\"500\" }", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

}
```